# Why isn't there an equivalent of StringBuilder for other immutable types?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

StringBuilder exists purely for the reason that strings in .NET are immutable, that is that traditional string concatenation can use lots of resources (due to lots of String objects being created).

So, **since an Int32 is also immutable** why don't classes exist for multiple addition for example?

Comment: And what should IntBuilder support? Adding of number?

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question. StringBuilder is necessary because string concatenation uses a lot of resources; StringBuilder is an *optimization*. Int addition does not use a lot of resources; therefore there is no need to optimize it.  The immutability of the types are irrelevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A concatenated string gets longer, which requires heap memory allocations and memory copies.
These get more expensive the longer the string gets, ergo we've a helper class (i.e. `StringBuilder`) to minimise the amount of copying that goes when when strings are **concatenated**.

Ints aren't concatinated, as you multiply ints you don't need more memory to hold the result of two multiplied ints, you just need another int (or the same int if it's `*=`).

You'd only need a helper class if you need to **concatenate** ints into some form of list . . . oh wait, `List<int>`!

Answer (score 8):

There is. There's `UriBuilder` for building `Uri` objects.

What would an `Int32Builder` do? What meaningful operation on a single integer is going to be more convenient and/or more performant through use of such a class?

For an XXXBuilder class to make sense, the following have to hold:

1. The class or struct is immutable.
2. Changing the value by replacing it with one based on the previous (e.g. `someString += "abc"` or `someDate = someDate.AddDays(1)`) has to be relatively expensive (true in the former example more than the latter) and/or relatively convoluted to code.
3. The requirement for such a XXXBuilder class is common enough that it makes sense to provide it rather than just letting those who do need it code their own.

None of the above applies to `int`. They do apply to `string` and `Uri`. I don't think reference vs value type is particularly relevant except that cases where point 2 fits are also going to be cases where a class is almost certainly a better design choice than a value type.

Indeed, the combination of point 1 and point 2 is relatively uncommon in .NET. Some would argue less common than it should be (those who favour heavy use of immutable types). And if we can avoid point 2, then we would, wouldn't we? Nobody will think "I'll code this to be expensive and clumsy and provide a builder class". Rather they may on occasion think "The downside to my well thought-out immutability is that while it gives me many advantages it makes some operations expensive and clumsy, so I'll provide a builder class as well".

Comment: I really think it is primarily about #3.  DateTime is an example where you could almost see a use for a builder, but there are so many methods available on the DateTime type that you don't need a seperate builder.

Comment: @tcarvin But that relates to #2 - using what's there doesn't have to involve much cost or convoluted code.

Comment: To my mind, the real question should be "why aren't there more immutable versions of mutable types".  It's trivial to write a method which given an `IList<T>` produces an immutable copy, but if the original `IList<T>` is already immutable, copying the list is a pure waste of time and memory.  Unfortunately, there's no standard way to query an `IList<T>` to find out whether it's immutable (being `ReadOnly` is *NOT* the same thing!).

Answer (score 4):

`Int32` is a **value** type.

`String` is a **reference** type. `StringBuilder` exists *because* `String` is an immutable **reference** type. `String` is also a **collection** of `Char` - so many allocations happen when you concatenate strings - `StringBuilder` makes these allocations beforehand, making creation of concatenated strings much more efficient. This is not an issue with value types.

Comment: I don't think int being a value type is as relevant as it being much simpler than string. Now, that's a big part of why it's a value type and string a reference type, but I think it's the simplicity that led to that choice that is the important thing, rather than the choice that was based on that simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Because Int32 is a value type, usually allocated on the stack (or within the body of a heap object). The compiler will automatically reuse the memory location when adding many value types in a loop for example.

The answer is basically "because of an implementation detail which means it is unnecessary".

The fact that string concatenation is slow, leading to a requirement for `StringBuilder`, is itself an implementation detail.

Value types can have their lifetime tracked because they have value type semantics. Whether this occurs is an implementation detail. In practice it does, and that is the reason why there is no need for an IntBuilder class.

Comment: "Int32 is a value type, allocated on the stack" is true **sometimes**.

Comment: I had a feeling this was the difference, but how does the compiler automatically reuse the stack location?

Comment: @Oded: Edited to account for value types as members.

Comment: @Ben, Oded didn't mean that. He meant that there is nothing that can guarantee that an Int32 is stored on the stack: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx It's merely an implementation detail that you cannot/shouldn't rely upon.

Comment: @m.edmondson: I am not sure what you mean by "how". It just generates code which overwrites the previous value at that location with the new value.

Comment: @m.edmondson The compiler analyzes every variable for its lifetime. It knows when a particular variable is no longer used, so it frees up that spot on the stack.

Comment: -1: I'm with Darin, stack used in this context is incorrect and confuses the issue

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Technically that is true - a large value type might be stored on the heap with a pointer on the stack. However it remains the case that for value types the compiler can reuse the space once it is out of scope (for example on next loop iteration).

Comment: @Ben: Your statement "The compiler will automatically reuse the **stack** location when adding many value types" is incorrect if the int happens to be on the heap (as a member of an object, or a member in an array etc etc). Change it and I'll happily remove my downvote.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, The answer is basically "because of an implementation detail which means it is unnecessary". The fact that string concatenation is slow, leading to a requirement for StringBuilder, is itself an implementation detail. Lots of things are implementation details but you still have to know about them. Value types can have their lifetime tracked because they have value type semantics. Whether this occurs is an implementation detail. In practice it does, and that is the reason why there is no need for an IntBuilder class.

Comment: @Ben: "Value types are almost always allocated on the stack" I couldn't disagree more. Yes "Value types declared as variables in functions (and that aren't captured in lambda expressions) are almost always allocated on the stack", but most types, value types included are used as members on classes, which will be allocated on the heap, ergo, most value types will be declared on the heap.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier: I have already edited the answer to address your point. Value types involved in repeated addition in a loop in a way analogous to the classic use-case for StringBuilder, will generally be allocated on the stack.